# How do I convert OVERLAPPED struct to js-ctypes?

Tags: javascript, winapi, jsctypes

I'm trying to get ReadFileEx working in js-ctypes and ran into a bit of an obstacle converting the OVERLAPPED struct to js-ctypes. Any tips on the translation would be much appreciated:

```
typedef struct _OVERLAPPED {
  ULONG_PTR Internal;
  ULONG_PTR InternalHigh;
  union {
    struct {
      DWORD Offset;
      DWORD OffsetHigh;
    };
    PVOID  Pointer;
  };
  HANDLE    hEvent;
} OVERLAPPED, *LPOVERLAPPED;
```

This is not right, but I started with

```
const struct_overlapped = new ctypes.StructType("overlapped",
  [ {"Internal": ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    {"InternalHigh": ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    [ [ {"Offset": ctypes.uint32_t},
        {"OffsetHigh": ctypes.uint32_t} ],
      {"Pointer": ctypes.voidptr_t} ],
    {"hEvent": ctypes.voidptr_t} ]);
```

but I'm not sure how to handle the "union" and the second struct.

**Update.** Maybe something like this?

```
const struct_offset = new ctypes.StructType("offsetStruct",
  [ {"Offset": ctypes.uint32_t},
    {"OffsetHigh": ctypes.uint32_t} ]);

const struct_overlapped = new ctypes.StructType("overlapped",
  [ {"Internal": ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    {"InternalHigh": ctypes.uint64_t.ptr},
    [ {"offsetStruct": ctypes.struct_offset},
      {"Pointer": ctypes.voidptr_t} ],
    {"hEvent": ctypes.voidptr_t} ]);
```

But I get an error

> Message: Error: struct field descriptors must contain one property

**Update 2.** Maybe the first attempt will work?

Answer (score 0):

Before getting in overlapped structs and completion routines, the solution to these synchronus blocking APIs such as WinAPI, COM, Objective-C, GTK, XCB, X11, etc etc etc is to use works.

Note that some callbacks in GTK and ObjC and X11 have to be on the main thread. And its not possible to use `dispatch_queue` to set up the callback on the mainthread from workers due to an unfixable bug.

Windows is full on fun with workers no sweat.

I personally love PromiseWorkers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PromiseWorker - I hacked it up so I can call functions from the mainthread from the PromiseWorker (you might not need this so I wouldn't recommend copying the PromiseWorker boiler plate from my addons)

Comment: Worried about this note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChromeWorker - This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Will using ChromeWorker allow my add-on to be approved?

Comment: @tofutim, that warning is meant for web developers. ChromeWorkers are highly recommended for addons, as it puts everything off the main thread. In the future everything will be from a ChromeWorker, that's the plan. Well they said they want it all off the mainthread, which I guess is a ChromeWorker.